# Handling the Back Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyevent

I am working on the following code:

```
private class HandleBackButton implements OnKeyListener
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(arg1==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                showResults(0);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I am somewhat new to android and my purpose is to operate the above code when the back button is clicked. User can click the back button any time. But, how can I set this listener to the Activity? I can't find something like `this.setOnKeyListener()`.

I am using Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the `onKeyDown()` method of Activity.
You don't have to set a listener then.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            showResults(0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Optionally you can also override `onBackPressed()` if your api level is >= 5.

Comment: I used onBackPressed(). Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

For the Activity you should override `onBackPressed` which is invoked when you press the back button.  `OnKeyListener` dispatches key events to the view. You find setOnKeyListener defined in the View class

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key
>   event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before
>   the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware
>   keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this
>   listener.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the onBackPressed() suggestion. I really appreciate it. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    showResults(0);
}
```